# How do I remove some characters from my String

Tags: java, string

i want to remove all of the following chars from my string

> ">[],-"

at the moment im doing this. but there must be a more efficient way

```
newString = myString.replace(">","").replace("[","").replace("]","")....
```

Comment: Well, you could use regex, but then you'd have to escape special chars. And what kind of efficiency are you talking about? Runtime or your own (i.e. lines of code)?

Comment: Worrying about the “efficiency” of this particular problems indicates premature optimization; I highly doubt that *this* method is the bottleneck of your application. Please take your time to find out where your application is *really* slow and in need of optimization.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a regex that describes all the characters you want to replace, with the method that replaces everything matching the regex:

```
newString = myString.replaceAll("[<>\\[\\],-]", "");
```

(edited: I don't think `<>` are supposed to be escaped, actually. And I forgot to double up the backslashes since they'll be interpreted twice: once by the Java compiler, and again by the regular expression engine.)

Comment: What if I want to keep new lines ?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `replaceAll` method of the `String` class.

You can form a character class consisting of the characters you want to delete. And the replacement string will be empty string `""`.

But the characters you want to delete which you'll be putting in the character class might be regex meta-characters and hence need to be escaped. You can manually escape them as many answers show, alternatively you can use the `Pattern.quote()` method.

```
String charToDel = ">[],-";
String pat = "[" + Pattern.quote(charToDel) + "]";
String str = "a>b[c]d,e-f";
str = str.replaceAll(pat,"");
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/zNPxz)

Answer (score 4):

More efficient performace-wise: yes. You can't "delete" chars from a String so you have t create a new one anyway. Consider a switch/case based solution:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
  switch(s.getCharAt(i)) {
    case '>':
    case '[':
    case ']':
    case ',':
    case '-': break;
    default: sb.append(s.getCharAt(i));
  }
}
s = sb.toString();
```

Comment: There's a typo in the code: it's not s.getCharAt(i)   but s.charAt(i)

Answer (score 2):

```
newString = myString.replaceAll("[>\\[\\],-]", "");
```

The backslashes are to escape the '[' because the first argument is actually a regular expression.

Comment: Uhh... you are going to want to wrap those characters in a character class (`[]`) because you are looking for any of them on their own, not a sequence of all of them in a row...

Comment: Don't think that is going to work.  That will only match cases that the symbols are all together in that order.

Comment: Its still not working. I'm getting all of those characters in my string

Answer (score 2):

Using the replace / replaceAll methods causes a new Pattern to be compiled each time. So if you are doing this multiple times I would strongly suggest either looping through the characters or creating a single regular expression to use repeatedly.

Comment: Please don't loop through the characters yourself; but do "create the regex" (a new `Pattern` instance, in Java) if this is important. See the Java doc for java.util.regex.Pattern, which also gives a basic overview of the regular expression syntax supported by Java's regex engine.

Answer (score 1):

```
newString = myString.replaceAll("[>\\[\\],-]", "");
```

Comment: sort of works but its removing a lot more than I want. it removed alm ost of all the data

Comment: @user521180: edited it a bit, try once again. Can you give us a data sample if it still doesn't work the way you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through each character, appending them one by one to a StringBuilder() unless they match one of the characters you are removing.

But I'm not sure that'd be a whole lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

use regex; the string relaceAll method takes the reegex as first argument and the replacement text as second argument; for example

```
return myString.replaceAll(">|\\[|\\]|,|-";, "");
```

Comment: If you don't be able to provide the whole link, better take it out of your question. Your answer could be seen to contain content of spam.