# Code that needs to print a Scanner string without vowels

Tags: java, string, printing, character

I need to write a program that takes a string, and prints out the string text with all the vowels removed, except when a word starts with it.

The code I've written is halfway there, but I cannot figure out why it will not return the whole string and it does not remove all the vowels. Say I input the phrase "Desirable property area". The program prints the string, "Dirlp" instead of "Dsrbl prprty ar "

Can anybody advise on how I can improve the code to make this work? Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print ("Enter some text, then hit enter: ");
    String text = in.nextLine();

    takeOutVowel (text);
    System.out.println ();
}

static void takeOutVowel (String s)
{
    char ch = s.charAt(0);                              //character to be printed
    System.out.print (ch);
    int nextCh = 1;                                 //determines the position of the next character
    int increase = 1;                               //increase is how much i will increase by in the for loop; takes the position of vowels into                                                        //consideration so they can be skipped

    for (int i = 1; i <= s.length(); i += increase)
    {
        ch = s.charAt (nextCh);

        if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u')
        {
            nextCh++;
            ch = s.charAt (nextCh); 

            while (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u');
            {
                nextCh++;
                ch = s.charAt (nextCh);

                if (nextCh >= s.length())
                {
                    ch = ' ';
                    break;          
                }   

            } 
        }

        System.out.print (ch);  
        nextCh++;
        ch = s.charAt (nextCh);

        if (ch == ' ')                                  //if the previous position was a space, then this will allow for the vowel to be printed
        {
            System.out.print ("" + ch + s.charAt(nextCh + 1));
            nextCh++;
        }

        increase = nextCh;


    }
```

Thanks for all the answers so far - very helpful! I'm not allowed to use arrays or anything not covered yet, so I've amended the code to what it is below. It compiles fine but when I run the program and enter the Scanner text, I get a message that says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 27
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
at Vowels.noVowels(Vowels.java:20)
at Vowels.main(Vowels.java:11)
```

I can't figure what the problem is now. Thank you again for all the help!

```
    import java.util.*;

class Vowels
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print ("Enter some text, then hit enter: ");
        String text = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println (noVowels(text));
    }

    static String noVowels (String s)
    {
        String noVowels = "" + s.charAt(0);                 //Starts a new string with the first character of the input text

        for (int i = 1; i <= s.length(); i++)
        {
            if (isVowel(s.charAt(i)) && s.charAt(i-1) != ' ')       //if the character is a vowel and it's previous character wasn't a space, then this is a vowel to be                                                replaced
            {
                noVowels = noVowels.concat("");
            }

            else
            {
                noVowels = noVowels.concat("" + s.charAt(i));
            }
        }

        return noVowels; 
    }

    static boolean isVowel (char ch)
    {
        if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u')
        {
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430112/how-do-i-remove-some-characters-from-my-string ( I mean, you could just have a simple regexp with every vowel...)

Comment: If the word starts with a vowel, you dont need to remove any vowels from that word ?

Comment: I assume your index out of range is because in your `for` loop you have your condition as `i <= s.length();`. Let's say your String is "hello" - the length is 5, but `s.charAt(5)` doesn't exist. The max position in the array is 4.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem easily. Iterate over String and check the vowel. If no vowel than append the result. Try

```
static void takeOutVowel(String s) {
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
    String[] words = s.split(" +");
    for (String word : words) {
        res.append(word.charAt(0)); //Skip the first char  
        for (int i = 1; i < word.length(); i++) {
            char ch = word.charAt(i);
            if (!isVowel(ch)) { // Check the vowel
                res.append(ch);
            }
        }
        res.append(' ');
    }

    System.out.println(res);
} 

static boolean isVowel(char ch){
  ch=Character.toLowerCase(ch); // Make it case-insensitive.
 return ch=='a' ||ch=='e' ||ch=='i' ||ch=='o' ||ch=='u';
}
```

Comment: This was super helpful, thank you! I am not allowed to use arrays is the problem. Is there another way around it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with a regular expression as well. The first example demonstrates how to simply remove vowels.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String noVowels = takeOutVowel("Hello how are you?");
    System.out.println(noVowels); // prints "Hll hw r y?"
}

// This will remove all vowels from any String
private static String takeOutVowel(String s)
{
    return s.replaceAll("[aeiou]", ""); 
}
```

But now to satisfy your requirement of ignoring the first letter of a word if it is a vowel (which means we will ignore it no matter what), you just need to edit the `takeOutVowel` method a bit.

```
static String takeOutVowel (String s)
{
   // split your string so we can examine each word separately
   String[] words = s.split(" ");
   String noVowels = "";

   for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
       char firstChar = words[i].charAt(0);
       String temp = words[i].substring(1, words[i].length()).replaceAll("[aeiou]", "");
       noVowels += firstChar + temp + " ";
   }

   return noVowels;
}
```

Comment: How you skip the first char? According to OP requirement the result should be like `Hll hw ar y?`

Comment: @Masud You are right, I glazed over that requirement. I will write something up, and edit my answer. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: @adback03 thanks so much for your help with this! I'm not allowed to use arrays for this program. Do you know of an alternate method? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This works for your following requirement - Remove all vowels except for when the word starts with a vowel.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter some text, then hit enter: ");
    String text = in.nextLine();
    takeOutVowel(text);
    System.out.println();
}

static void takeOutVowel(String s) {
    String[] array = s.split(" ");                          // Split sentence into words and store them in an array.
    StringBuilder finalString = new StringBuilder();
    for (String word : array) {                             //For each word in the array
        char ch = word.toLowerCase().charAt(0);             //check if the lower case first character is a vowel.
        if(ch != 'a' && ch != 'e' && ch != 'i' && ch != 'o' && ch != 'u'){    // When it is not, replace all the vowels.
            finalString = finalString.append(word.replaceAll("[aeiou]", "")).append(" ");  
        }else{
            finalString = finalString.append(ch).append(word.replaceAll("[aeiou]", "")).append(" ");// When it is , replace all the vowels except the first character.
        }
    }
    System.out.println(finalString);
}
}
```