# Xstream ignore whitespace characters

Tags: character, whitespace, xstream

I load data from XML into java classes using xstream library. The texts in several tags are very long and take more than one line. Such formatting causes that I have in Java class field text with additional characters like `\n\t`. Is there any way to load data from XML file without these characters?

Xml tag is declared in two lines. Opening tag is in the first line, then I have very long text, and the closing tag is declared in second line.

Comment: You need to post some examples of whats happening. You could regex them off or format your strings with java.string.format

Comment: What example do you need?

Comment: Your xml.. how your reading it in exactly (looping etc), your beginning result (what your string looks like when first read)and the end result your trying to achieve

Comment: <SomeTag>very_long_text
 </SomeTag>
 
 The closing tag (</SomeTag>) is in next line. In java field I have string "very_long_text\n\t". I use this text to compare it with another one. But with this additional characters the result of comparison is unpredictable.

Comment: are the characters trailing always \n\t ?

Comment: Not always, depending on whether the text in the tag is declared in one line or in more lines

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex or the string split method.

```
String string = "004-034556";
String[] parts = string.split("-");
String part1 = parts[0]; // 004
String part2 = parts[1]; // 034556
```

Just split your string. In your case it would be

```
String wantedText = parts[0];
```

Another solution would be to put your values into a string array, loop the array, match and remove any characters you dont want.

You can see how to match and remove [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430112/how-do-i-remove-some-characters-from-my-string)

Comment: I think about rather global solution of this problem. In your suggestion I would have to handle each of such field.