# Parsing a file with specific file format

Tags: java, parsing

Hi i'm relatively new to java and i'm wondering how to go about parsing a certain file format into a 2D array.

The file format consists of a a comma separating values with < and /> separating an addition set of values.

```
<a,b,c/><x,y,z>
<...
<...
```

Each line will then be inputted into an array[ ] [ ] where the first set will go into the first column and the next set to the second.

The line should then be outputted to look like this.

```
a, b, c
x ,y ,z
...
```

Any help would be great thanks.

EDIT: this is what i have so far

```
public static main (String args[])
{
    //Open file, read to get number of lines of file = numLine

    int[][] array = new int[numLine][numLine]

    for (int i = 0; i < numLine; i++)
    {
        //Unsure how to write element/line split
        array[i][i] = //input each element to array
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you written so far?

Comment: Voted to close as too broad. There are dozens of ways to tackle this. Most introductory Java books will provide a couple of suitable approaches within the first five chapters at most.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify this to suit your need. I added some comments and so you might want to pay attention to them.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

    String[][] array = new String[numLine][numLine];//declaring the matrix

    int r=0 , c=0;//declaring the index of the matrices column and row

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        line = line.replaceAll("[<>]", "");//removing > and < so we gonna have a,b,c/x,y,z
        String[] col = line.split("/");// spliting using / and we gonna have  a,b,c    x,y,z

        for (String row : col) {
            //a,b,c or x,y,z
            String[] oneCol = row.split(",");
            for (String oneRow : oneCol) {
                if(c >= numLine){
                    c = 0;
                    break;
                }
                array[r][c] = oneRow;
                c++;
            }
            r++;
            //System.out.println();
        }
        c = 0;

    }

    sc.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Young Millie pointed out, what have you attempted so far?  That being said, there are several approaches you may take, one of them being the following.

A valid attempt would be to read the file line by line, then remove all occurrences of the symbols using [replaceAll(...)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4430181/7750124) (which is further explained [in their java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)) but instead you could use the following replace:

```
String line = "<a,b,c/><x,y,z>";
line = line.replaceAll("[<>]", "");
System.out.println("1. " + line);
```

with a result of:

```
1. a,b,c/x,y,z
```

and then we split split the string on "/", resulting in two arrays of your required strings:

```
String[] lines = line.split("/");
System.out.println("1. " + lines[0]);
System.out.println("2. " + lines[1]);
```

with a result of:

```
1. a,b,c
2. x,y,z
```